# Selenium Javascript not able to click on link

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am new to using Selenium and Javascript.

```
<li j:showif="aLoaded && !loggedIn" style_display="" style="">
  <a href="/#dialog/login">Sign in</a>
</li>
```

My Selenium Javascript code is:

```
driver.wait(function () {
  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Sign in"));
}, 5000);

var signInLink = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.linkText("Sign in"));
signInLink.click();
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Wait timed out after 5104ms
```

Comment: Have you tried webdriver.By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Sign in')]") ?

Comment: NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[contains(text(),'Sign in')]"}

Comment: Sorry, should have been webdriver.By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]")

Comment: Is the link embedded in an iframe?